# Easy way to determine to determine whether $q(x)$ is irreducible in $Z_{29}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $q(x)=x^4+9x^2+12 \in \mathbb Z_{29}[x].$ Explain the steps that would suffice to determine whether $q(x)$ is irreducible in $Z_{29}[x].$

**My attempt:**
$q(x)$ doesn't have any roots, so $q(x)$ doesn't have any linear facrors, so we only have to consider quadratic factors of the form $x^2+ax+b.$ How to show whether $q(x)$ has quadratic factors or not?

Comment: Hint: Consider the equation $X^2 + 9X + 12$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{29}[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminant of $t^2+9t+12$ is $81-48=33\equiv 2^2\pmod{29}$, so 
$$ t^2+9t+12 \equiv (t-11)(t-9)\pmod{29}$$
and
$$ x^4+9x^2+12 \equiv (x-3)(x+3)(x^2-11)\pmod{29} $$
provides a complete factorization, since $11$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{29}$:
$$\left(\frac{11}{29}\right)=\left(\frac{29}{11}\right)=\left(\frac{7}{11}\right)=-\left(\frac{11}{7}\right)=-\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)=-1. $$